# XML Schema: Complex type with attribute and content depending on value

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am working on an XML schema to define the structure of a text. I have the following table:[image]

The output of the unit (meters or yards) depends on the previous distance values.

Valid XML snippets would be:

```
<distance value=“30“>thirty</distance><unit>meters</unit>
<distance value=“20“>twenty</distance><unit>yards</unit>
```

Thus, the unit depends on the distance value and the distance element text must represent the value in the distance attribute.

How could this be modeled?

Comment: Can you use XSD 1.1, or are you limited to XSD 1.0?

Comment: I can use whatever I want. Thus, XSD 1.1 is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

XSD 1.0 cannot generally constrain attribute values based on element values.

XSD 1.1 can generally constrain attribute values based upon element values via [assertions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions), but cannot relate word forms of numbers to numeric forms of numbers.   XSD 1.1 *could* handle the constraint where `thirty`, `fourty`, or `fifty` use `meter` units, while `twenty` and `sixty` use `yard` units (the peculiarity of such an example notwithstanding).

Schematron might be used to enforce a relationship between word forms and numeric forms using XSLT; see [Number To Word Conversion Program using XSLT](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1924/Number-To-Word-Conversion-Program-using-XSLT) for an example of such XSLT conversion code.